# Perl split at defined pattern position

Tags: regex, perl, split

Is there any way to break a string at defined position of a pattern by using perl split function? For example, by using `@array=split(/pattern/, $string)` one gets array of split `$string` but parts of string defined by pattern are missing in that array. Is it possible to specify which position of a pattern to split at, such that all pieces of initial `$string` are contained in `@array`?

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of strings you'd like to split and where you'd like to split them?

Comment: For example, pattern "tggg" will split the string aaaatgggccc into aaaa and ccc. What I would like to do is to define the splitting position inside the pattern and say, split the string after second pattern character in order to get: aaaatg and ggccc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your example it looks like you want to split at a point, say, after `tg` and before `gg`.

Because `split` uses a regular expression you can use *look-around assertions*.

Read about them under [Extended Patterns in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)

For example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'aaaatgggccc';

my @fields = split /(?<=tg)(?=gg)/, $s;

print "$_\n" for @fields;
```

**output**

```
aaaatg
ggccc
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mat's answer is good and is probably what I would use.  However, for completeness, there is another way that might suit:

```
my $pattern = qr/MY_PATTERN/;
my @array   = /($pattern)($string)?/g;
```

The `/g` modifier causes the pattern to match repeatedly.  The `?` is optional, depending on the precise effect you wish to achieve.